# Installing Magento - Error in File

Tags: php, magento

I'm completely new to Magento and I'm having trouble installing it on my local server using WAMP. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Error in file: "C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\code\core\Mage\ImportExport\sql\importexport_setup\install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 Error on rename of '.\magentoempty\#sql-598_ccd.frm' to '.\magentoempty\catalog_product_link_attribute_int.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

Trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.2')
#2 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.2')
#3 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

I got this error after I clicked Continue on the Configuration step. I checked the database and 326 empty tables were added.

Then when I refresh the page, I get a new error:

```
Error in file: "C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\code\core\Mage\ImportExport\sql\importexport_setup\install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'importexport_importdata' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `importexport_importdata` (
  `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Id' ,
  `entity` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity' ,
  `behavior` varchar(10) NOT NULL default 'append' COMMENT 'Behavior' ,
  `data` text NULL default '' COMMENT 'Data' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) COMMENT='Import Data Table' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

Trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.2')
#2 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.2')
#3 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 C:\wamp\www\magentoempty\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Help!

Comment: Give permission to file?

Comment: Problem is the said file - #sql-598_ccd.frm - cannot be found! It might be a temporary file that's why its not there